# How to remove false matches from FLANNBASED Matcher in OPENCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf, flann

*[Request you to read question details before marking it duplicate or down-voting it. I have searched thoroughly and couldn't find a solution and hence posting the question here.]*

I am trying to compare **one image with multiple images and get a list of ALL matching images.** I do NOT want to draw keypoints between images.

My solution is based on the following source code:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp

The above source code matches **one image with multiple images and get best matching image.**

I have modified the above sample and generated:

```
 vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;
 vector<vector<DMatch>> good_matches;
```

Now my question is how do I apply nearest neighbor search ratio to get good matches for multiple images?

**Edit 1:**

My implementation is as follows:

1. For each image in the data-set, compute SURF descriptors.
2. Combine all the descriptors into one big matrix.
3. Build a FLANN index from the concatenated matrix.
4. Compute descriptors for the query image.
5. Run KNN search over the FLANN index to find **top 20 or less** best matching image. K is set as 20.
6. Filter out all the inadequate matches computed in the previous step. (How??)

I have successfully done steps number 1 to 5. I am facing problem in step number 6 wherein I am not able to remove false matches.

Comment: So you already have found multiple matches for one image and now want to find the k best matches?

Comment: Yes. I am able to find the matches. I have set k as 20 because I want to find "all" similar images.

Comment: Ok, so you basically want find the false positives in your k best result? [Didn't you ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935494/opencv-surf-algorithm-giving-lots-of-false-positives) already?

Comment: Initially, I was using BruteForce matcher when I asked that question.  Using BruteForce matcher, I  was able to remove false positives and get good results. Unfortunately, the speed of using BruteForce matcher is extremely slow. Now I am using FLANN matcher and again stuck at the same stage.

Comment: So you want to find images that are similar to your query image? Why not use BOV-descriptor, or other global image-descriptor? You best edit your answer saying what you want to accomplish overall, including sample images.

Comment: @Unapiedra, Iam trying to find out duplicates in one folder. The folder consist of 5000 images. My solution is completely similar to the link I mentioned in the question. The only difference is that I want to find multiple matching images instead of the best one.

Comment: Thanks, please put that in the question (I can't upvote otherwise).

Answer (score 12):

There are two answers to your problem. The first is that you should be using a completely different technique, the second answer is how to actually do what you asked for.

## Use a different method

You want to find duplicates of a given query image. Traditionally, you do this by comparing **global** image descriptors, not *local* feature descriptors.

The simplest way to do this would be by aggregating the local feature descriptors into a local descriptor. The standard method here is "bag of visual words". In OpenCV this is called Bag-Of-Words (like `BOWTrainer`, [BOWImgDescriptorExtractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html#bowimgdescriptorextractor) etc). Have a look at the documentation for using this.

There is some example code in `samples/cpp/bagofwords_classification.cpp`

The *benefits* will be that you get more robust results (depending on the implementation of what you are doing now), and that the matching is generally faster.

## Use your method

I understand that you want to remove points from the input that lead to false positives in your matching.

You can't remove points from FLANN([1](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/), [2](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_visapp09.pdf), [3](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/binary_matching_crv2012.pdf)). FLANN builds a tree for fast search. Depending on the type of tree, removing a node becomes impossible. Guess what, FLANN uses a KD-tree which doesn't (easily) allow removal of points.

> FlannBasedMatcher does not support masking permissible matches of descriptor sets because flann::Index does not support this.

I would suggest using a radius search instead of a plain search. Alternatively look at the L2-distance of the found matches and in your code write a function to see whether the distance falls below a threshold.

### Edit

I should also note that you can rebuild your flann-tree. Obviously, there is a performance penalty when doing this. But if you have a large number of queries and some features coming up as false-positives way too often, it might make sense to do this once.

You need the functions `DescriptorMatcher::clear()` and then `DescriptorMatcher::add(const vector<Mat>& descriptors)` for this. [Referenz](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=bruteforcematcher#bruteforcematcher).

Comment: I tried the second method. It is not removing false positives. :-(

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you need to define "inadequate matches", without this definition you can't do anything.

There are several loose definitions that spring to mind:

1: inadequate matches = match with distance > pre-defined distance

In this case a flann radius search may more appropriate as it will only give you those indexes within the predefined radius from the target:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html#flann-index-t-radiussearch

2: inadequate matches = match with distance > dynamically defined distance based on the retrieved k-nn

This is more tricky and off the top of my head i can think of two possible solutions:

2a: Define some ratio test based on the distance the first 1-NN such as:

base distance = distance to 1NN

inadequate match_k =  match distance_k >= a * base distance;

2b: Use a dynamic thresholding technique such as the Otsu threshold on the normalized distribution of distances for the k-nn, thus partitioning the the k-nn into two groups, the group that contains the 1-nn is the adequate group, the other is the inadequate group.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method,

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold.

Comment: I developed my application using BruteForce matcher as well as Flannn matcher. The results I got with BF matcher were perfect. I want the same kind of results with FLANN. The obvious reason for choosing Flann over BF matcher is speed.

Comment: @milanm FLANN is approximate, you can tune it's parameters to trade-off between speed/accuracy.

Comment: @milanm FLANN parameters doc. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html#flann::Index_ ,  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html#flann-index-t-knnsearch